# Get variables show up in sub-sub directory rewrites, .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
Options +Indexes  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ([^/]+/.*) index.php?dir=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

The htaccess lives in test.com/main/.htaccess
I can access test.com/main/ and test.com/index.php fine
test.com/main/directory gets rewritten to test.com/main/index.php?dir=/main/directory/ BUT test.com/main/directory stays in the url bar. This is good.

The problem is when I try to access sub-sub directories. When I access test.com/main/foler1/folder2 it gets rewritten to index.php?dir=/main/folder1/folder2/. This is also good, however test.com/main/folder1/folder2/?dir=/main/folder1/folder2/ shows up in the address bar instead of keeping test.com/main/folder1/folder2 in the url bar. This is the problem.

I want all sub directories, not just the direct children of main to keep the directory in the url bar while rewriting. The direct children do this fine, but any directories under that rewrite in a way where my get variables show up.

The purpose of this rewrite is so I don't have to copy in an index.php file into every newly created folder so copying the .htaccess into each folder defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add the solution I found while testing mootinator's solution.

Instead of linking to
test.com/main/foler1/folder2

link to
test.com/main/foler1/folder2/ (Include the slash!)

Redirection will successfully redirect to
index.php?dir=/main/folder1/folder2/

while
test.com/main/foler1/folder2/
stays in the url bar.

It's a somewhat hackish solution but it should work just fine.

Comment: Why are you rewriting on directories which exist?  The usual practice is to rewrite all directories or files which do *not* exist, then figure out in the code whether the URL was valid.

Comment: I updated my answer to solve the issue, assuming you do have a good reason for doing things this way at any rate =)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `RewriteRule ([^/]+/.*) index.php?dir=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]` (The L prevents mod rewrite from processing any further rules if the rule is successful)  QSA appends any query string which may have been passed in.

Update:

The issue is that the server is rewriting the URL without the slash (visibly) as the URL with the slash, and including your rewrite rule as part of that.  The way around that would be to only process the rule when the URL ends with a slash eg:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+/.*/$) index.php?dir=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

This way it will do the rewrite in two separate steps:

1. Add the slash visibly.
2. Rewrite using your rule to index.php

Instead of:

1. Add the slash and rewrite to index.php visibly.

Comment: Well, this solution didn't work though I did notice something that I didn't notice before. If I load any sub-sub or sub-sub-sub directory while including a slash at the end, the rewriting performs correctly as always, but the get variables do not show up. I guess I can settle for this solution. I will simply have to check my automatically generated links to make sure they link with a slash at the end of the paths.  
Thanks for the help though!